# PHP hash_hmac() OS difference

Tags: php, windows

I need to sign my Amazon Product API request, the accepted code to do this is the following.

```
base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $request, $key, true));
```

This works great when I'm on 64bit Linux but fail when I'm on 64bit Windows 7. Has anyone got any ideas how to debug why hash_hmac provides different output between 64bit Linux and 64bit Windows?

Test code:

```
<?php
$test = "GET
webservices.amazon.com
/onca/xml
AWSAccessKeyId=00000000000000000000&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers%2CImages%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2009-01-01T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2009-01-06";
#echo $test;
echo base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $test, '1234567890', true));
```

**Edit** The correct output of the code above is `Nace+U3Az4OhN7tISqgs1vdLBHBEijWcBeCqL5xN9xg=`
The incorrect output is `X0UTct9XSJ/3k2gu6noyKhTlksx5ZbH4qAbCyW3zX48=`

The non-base64-encoded values are `5f451372df57489ff793682eea7a322a14e592cc7965b1f8a806c2c96df35f8f` for the incorrect and `35a71ef94dc0cf83a137bb484aa82cd6f74b0470448a359c05e0aa2f9c4df718` for the correct one when converted to hex. (it's raw binary output in the call)

**Edit 2** My guess right now is that even though the Windows 7 OS is 64bit the PHP binary is compiled as 32bit as I could not find a 64bit version on the php.net site.

**Edit 3** I'm actually pretty sure now that the problem is that the binary is 32bit. Most likely PHP on linux uses an OS version to calculate the hash while PHP on windows implements it's own version which causes the 32/64bit difference even though both OS are 64bit.

Comment: It might help to give us the incorrect output as well...

Comment: I did about 10 minutes before you commented that?...

Comment: @Martin: I too see only the correct output. Can you include the output from both the Linux and Windows systems?

Comment: Sorry! I misread, I will add the incorrect output. Also updating with my thoughts so far from further research.

Comment: @Martin can you show the failed results from before the base64_encode? Maybe somebody can see some telltale sign...

Comment: @Pekka the output is raw binary output, not really printable. The hex output differs as well, I'll paste it in but I don't think it'll help much.

Comment: Ugh! I just ran into this issue. I'm getting the same incorrect output and I'm on Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations, and welcome to the wonderful world of line endings. The problem you're having is a classic one: line endings in *nix are `\n`, and line endings in windows are `\r\n`. Try the following instead:

```
$test = "GET\n".
"webservices.amazon.com\n".
"/onca/xml\n".
"AWSAccessKeyId=00000000000000000000&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers%2CImages%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2009-01-01T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2009-01-06";
```

Comment: You ninjaed my own response, so have the rep. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working for me. I think it's my own confusion. On my linux box, it's working fine but only when I type everything on a separate line. When I put it on one line with manual insertion of newline, I get the SAME THING as on windows... which is not the right output. To make matters worse, I'm trying to replace \n or \r with some visible characters and printing it, yet it seems like neither are in my string. Maybe I should open a new question?

Comment: I was using single quotes. Doh! Didn't know the newlines wouldn't be interpreted in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the output with `mhash()`. It follows the same algorithm.

```
 hash_hmac("sha256", "data", "key");
```

is equivalent to

```
 bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_SHA256, "data", "key"));
```

So if there is no difference between these two, I surmise the error lies in the implementation of sha256. Either way, it's a bug. Report on php.net and demand a new build.

You could also test with `hash("sha256", "test");` on both platforms to debug further which one works correctly. "test" should become 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for leaving the question open since I did figure out the problem, and like most problems usually do it turned out to be PEBCAC.

The answer is not 32 versus 64bit but rather line endings. Linux has \n while Windows has \r\n.

Write it all out on one line and explicitly use \n and it should work.

```
$test = "GET\nwebservices.amazon.com\n/onca/xml\nAWSAccessKeyId=00000000000000000000&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers%2CImages%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2009-01-01T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2009-01-06";
echo base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $test, '1234567890', true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that with respect to Amazon Seller Web Service, the order of the parameters thats in your post string also matters, it seems they have a sort order which they maintain internally to all the post params, which is used to prepare the string that is used to generate the signature. if you use the sketchpad you can get the order of the params, i did not notice it on any documentation.

Comment: This answer does not seem to be having any relevance to the question, the OP clearly states the problem is with the OS platforms, not with the parameters which is being sent.